# Typescript tips popup just display a final analyzing type result ,but not the intermediate definition

Tags: typescript

Typescript tips just display a final analyzing type result, but not the intermediate definition. only work with ‘typeof’.

```js
function testX <T extends {a: any}>(t: T): Pick<T, 'a'> {
  return (null as any)
}
// when cursor move on 'res' ,just display the intermediate definition
const res = testX({a: 's', b: 'b'})

// when cursor move on 'resType', it will display the final analyzing type result
type resType = typeof res
```

[code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygDUQHgCqIoAeqYAJmogN4CGAXIjWAJ4C+AfABRQN4CUDAAowIAa3wAaRAHIa09tQCwAKESIATiigh1STmBAAbQ40pNmfFaxUB6G4gDuACxRIIOtHHWIAtnABuKIgIMppo0ogSAFYgGIhkMGgADoY0zMguiDBgqOo+KAk0qPEowNkwsAgqEAhxYYgAvMjoWJy0DNLhUgBGHd3SrJbKtvbOroju6p7efoHBSNJheMxJKNJSFY4wxvGJKWkZQWVgNCZMp8wAXtkA5sgrQWFGUCpQDxroy6uN96twwB80EA)

[the intermediate definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR3Sj.png)

[only work with ‘typeof’](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0GnU.png)

[Related issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39262)